# Swift - Using Next Token to load more items on AWS AppSync List Query

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am loading a Collection View filled with posts via an AWS AppSync List Query. I want to list unlimited items and I just increased the default limit of 10 to 50 items.

"NexToken" is defined as 
*an identifier that was returned from the previous call to this operation, which can be used to return the next set of items in the list.* How can I get this token?

What would be the best way to load unlimited items?

```
   func getFeed(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {

    var array = [Post]()

    appSyncClient?.fetch(query: ListPostsQuery(limit: 50 , nextToken: nil), cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheData) {(result, error) in
               if error != nil {
                   print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                   return
               }
               result?.data?.listPosts?.items?.forEach {
                array.append(Post(postID: $0!.post, author: $0!.author!))
               }

         self.UserFeedCollectionView.reloadData()
         completion(self.allPostsArray)
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a service side way to load unlimited items. On the client side, you will still have to recursively call appSyncClient.fetch() when there is a non-nil nextToken to retrieve the next page of data, then you can append the new results to your existing set of data.

Ideally you limit to something like 50 and then when the user reaches the end of the page, you can use the nextToken to retrieve the next set of data.

`limit` has a maxiumum of 1000 (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1496) if that helps your use case, but be mindful that the client side code would still need to handle the case when nextToken is non-nil.